# Find the word from the sentence in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to find the keyword of Documents from the sentence.

For Example, Documents

```
[
 {"keyword": "love"},
 {"keyword": "lovely"},
 {"keyword": "love you"},
 {"keyword": "i love you"},
 {"keyword": "hello"},
 {"keyword": "etc"},
]
```

the sentence `I am so lovely`, got the following result

```
[
 {"keyword": "love"},
 {"keyword": "lovely"}
]
```

i tried

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find({$text:{$search:"I am so lovely"}})
```

i got following result

```
[
 {"keyword": "love"},
 {"keyword": "lovely"},
 {"keyword": "love you"},
 {"keyword": "i love you"}
]
```

but i don`t want to get below because there is no "you" in sentence.

{"keyword": "love you"},
{"keyword": "i love you"}

Comment: the error says you have to create text index for that, you can google it or, see here [how to create text index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index).

Comment: thank you i created text index but it`s hard to get result that i want.

Comment: Why does it return `love` your statement doesn't have that word?

Comment: the statement is "I am so lovely"
there is love in lovely.

Comment: It seems your requirement is custom. there are 2 options in MongoDB [text-search](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/) and [regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) follow the documentation and implement accordingly.